# Cannot select disk in boot menu

Tags: windows-8, iso-image

I had some problems with Windows 8, so I decided to create a recovery disk. However, I only had another Windows 7 PC. So, I downloaded Windows 8 recovery disk ISO, and burned it onto a disk with FreeISOBurner. In my boot menu, I cannot select the disk. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the CD/DVD drive show up at all?

Comment: It wasn't showing up at first, but after I turned on UEFI and Legacy OS in my BIOS menu, it does show up. I am able to run the disk now, and it says `Loading files...`but after that, the computer shuts off automatically.